# Command Line Argument second highest number - C program

Tags: c, command-line

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
int a[50];
int n,i,large,s_large;
clrscr();

printf("\n Enter number of elements: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("\n Enter the elements: ");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}

large=s_large=a[0];

for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    if(large<a[i])
    {
        s_large=large;
        large=a[i];
    }
    else if(s_large<a[i] && a[i]!=large)
    {
        s_large=a[i];
    }
}

printf("\n The Second Largest Element in the given Array: %d", s_large);
getch();
}
```

Above is the working code for finding out the second largest number in c. I'm new to command line argument. So kindly help me converting this post to command line argument.

Comment: Look up the `argc` and `argv` arguments to `main`.

Comment: You'll need to define your main function in the orthodox style `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and then convert each of the arguments from `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]` to an integer, probably producing a warning or error if any of them is not convertible, and do your comparisons.  For second greatest, you need at least two arguments other than the program name (`argv[0]`); you can simply keep a record of the greatest and second greatest so far,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uses `argc` and `argv` for command line arguments in `c`.
 Command line arguments are found in the `argv` array - `argv[1], argv[2]` `etc`.
 and number of arguments are found in `argc`.

You execute the program as below.

```
./exe 1 2 4 6 3 5
 In this case `argc` will have `7` and argv will have as following
 arg[0]= exe,arg[1] = 1,arg[2] = 2,arg[3] = 4,arg[4] = 6,arg[5] = 3 and arg[6] = 5.
```

Your code will look like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i=0,num=0,large=INT_MIN, s_large=INT_MIN;

  printf("Number of arguments: %d\n", argc);
   //argv[0] is the program name
  for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
  {
     if(sscanf(argv[i], "%d", &num) !=1)
      break; //Not an integer

     printf("%d\n", num);
     if(large<num)
     {
        s_large=large;
        large=num;
     }
     else if(s_large<num && num !=large)
     {
       s_large=num;
     }

   }

   printf("\n\nThe Largest Number is %d",s_large);

   getch();
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: can you make that for second highest number

Comment: @BloggingBro Answer is already updated for finding second largest number

Comment: If enough of the numbers are negative, the code will give the wrong answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Edited accordingly.